# How to implement Single Sign Out using Auth.js?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm using Keycloak as my on-premise identity management system. I use Auth.js to secure my website and it works great when I use single-sign-on.

User goes to `example.com` and if he wants to get access to the private area he would be redirected to the `accounts.example.com` which is a Keycloak instance, and comes back logged-in.

However, when I logout user, the `accounts.example.com` is till logged in. So anyone can press that `login` button again and because of Single-Sign-On he would immediately gain access to everything.

How can I make sure that when user logs out of `example.com`, he is also logged out of `accounts.example.com`?